# Am I allowed to display the ubuntu logo?

Tags: logo

Morning,

As I get closer to setting up my services etc for my website am I allowed to display the ubuntu logo? There are some that don't allow it.

Answer (score 2):

The licencing for use of logo and other Ubuntu trademarks can be found at the Canonical site.

http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-policy

http://www.ubuntu.com/legal

There is a form you can use.

https://forms.canonical.com/trademark/

Comment: Note that [Ubuntu membership](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership) confers the right to use the Ubuntu logo on business cards.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are going to use it for. But if it's just for your personal website to show your support of Ubuntu, I would think that you are allowed to use the Ubuntu logo, but you have to follow some design guidelines.

You can read more about using Ubuntu logos and graphics here: http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo